# Canvas doesn't install correctly for using webppl and webppl-viz

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-canvas

I am trying to run a simple script in WebPPL using the command line, which runs the following visualization:

```
var fairCoin = function() { flip(0.5) ? 'h' : 't' };
viz(repeat(20, fairCoin))
```

Following the instructions on the GitHub repo, I have installed webppl, and have also installed webppl-viz by running `npm install probmods/webppl-viz` in the folder `~/.webppl`. I also installed node-canvas in the same folder by entering `npm install canvas`. However, I get the following error:

```
/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/src/util/bound.js:18
  return g2D || (g2D = canvas.instance(1,1).getContext('2d'));
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at context (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/src/util/bound.js:18:44)
    at textMark (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/src/util/bound.js:169:11)
    at Object.itemBounds [as item] (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/src/util/bound.js:259:3)
    at /Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega/src/scene/Bounder.js:36:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Bounder.proto.evaluate (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega/src/scene/Bounder.js:35:15)
    at Model.prototype.evaluate (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-dataflow/src/Graph.js:329:16)
    at Builder.proto.evaluate (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega/src/scene/Builder.js:227:26)
    at Model.prototype.evaluate (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-dataflow/src/Graph.js:329:16)
    at Model.prototype.propagate (/Users/sambarnett/.webppl/node_modules/webppl-viz/node_modules/vega-dataflow/src/Graph.js:161:22)
```

I suspect this is due to some of the dependencies not being installed properly, although I can't see how to fix this. I know that the WebPPL script runs correctly in the browser.